# Update multiple columns based on a single condition in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table -

```
q)t
a b  c
--------
1 10 100
3 20 200
2 30 300
1 40 400
2 50 500
```

I wish to update column b and c values based on a single 'if' condition on column a. For example -

```
t:update b:0 from t where a=1
t:update c:0 from t where a=1
```

I could use vector conditional but don't want to as it would evaluate the condition twice for each row and my table has large number of rows.

```
update b:?[a=1;0;b], c:?[a=1;0;c] from t
```

Is there any way I can do it in so that 'a=1' condition is evaluated only once for each row?

Edit : I earlier missed mentioning that I want 'b' and 'c' to take some other values in 'else' condition and not just retain their original values -

```
update b:?[a=1;0;-1], c:?[a=1;0;-1] from t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use a vector conditional without evaluating the condition twice, you can evaluate it first e.g.

```
q)x:t.a=1
q)x
10010b
q)update b:?[x;0;-1],c:?[x;0;-1] from t
a b  c
--------
1 0  0
3 -1 -1
2 -1 -1
1 0  0
2 -1 -1
```

Here you evaluate the condition and store the result in a variable, and then use that in the vector conditional

Alternatively you could do two update statements e.g.

```
t:update b:0, c:0 from t where a=1
t:update b:-1, c:-1 from t where a<>1
```

Comment: I like your first suggestion. 
My bad, I didn't mention the 'else' part in my question. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Jedi I have updated my answer to include your updated "else" clause. If you feel this answers your question, consider "accepting" the answer with the green checkmark to help others who have the same question in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
update b:0, c:0 from t where a=1
```

Comment: What if i have to provide some other values to b and c if a is not equal to 1? i.e. the 'else' part.

Comment: In the case you provided where the "else" is just retaining the existing value, that is the behaviour that will occur with @dlynch's answer - only records where a=1 will be updated, the rest will remain unchanged

Comment: See [_Q For Mortals_ 9.5.1 Basic update](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#951-basic-update)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary in your update with associated values for each column related to the a column.

```
update b:![1 2 3;-1 0 1]a,c:![1 2 3;-10 0 10]a from t

a b c
--------
1 -1 -10
3  1  10
2  0   0
1 -1 -10
2  0  0
```